# How to give feedback to a visual interface, from a dll call?

Tags: c#, dll, user-interface

**Architeture Overview:**

Language : C# Windows Form Project using Class Libraries to execute the crawler tasks

I am currently writing a interface (UI) that will be used to "debug" a crawler (or a set of crawlers) i wrote. Each crawler is a .dll

From the interface, i am going to invoke the .dlls and i don't want to have to wait for them to end their tasks (Crawling, parsing and building the lists of elements internally) to display the results on the interface.

**Question:**

Is there any way i can, somehow, send a feedback from the .dll to the interface ?

Maybe a progress bar, or after reading the elements, display them on the interface, before crawling the next element ?

What i want is something like that to be displayed on the interface (gridview or something), in real time.

```
Finished Crawling College X
Finished Crawling College Y
Problem Crawling College Z - ABORTING
Finished Crawling College K
```

and so on.

Whats a good way for doing it ?

I thought about sending the reference of the Visual Component to the .dll (or to a secundary .dll) so that it can update the visual component itself, in the middle of the execution. Is there any downside of doing it ? Do i break any good pratice by doing so ?

Thanks in advance,

Marcello.

Comment: So these are classes you wrote? Why not simply make a known type to all your DLLs (such as an interface exposing progress methods), and then interact with the executing DLL classes from the interface?

Comment: What you mean with Exposing Progress Methods ?

You talking about a class that is visible for both crawlers and UI, that will keep updating the UI after each step of the crawler ?

Like a "MidField Player"?

Comment: How are you running your crawlers?

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare Each Crawler is a .dll and I only call one Method of each .dll (which is sort of a main method), called StartCrawling().

After this method is invoked, it will do everything, calling secundary methods, in order to do the requests for html pages, parse the pages, and build the lists of elements in the memory.

No background worker or thread is used.
I hope it helps you understanding my architeture

Comment: So you are calling your crawler synchronously and locking the UI while it is running?

Comment: Exactly, the UI fires the crawlers and wait for them to end. Synchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you could do something like this:

```
 public interface ICrawler
 {
     void StartCrawling(Action<SomeCrawlingMessageType> callback);
 }
```

And have some class in your DLL that implements this. You then pass in a callback that your crawler class can invoke to send messages back to the invoker.

In your callback, you can then take the data passed to you and update the UI by invoking the UI updates asychronously, even from multiple crawlers.

Comment: Whats the name of this you are using ? I mean, what should i look after to do it ?

Action callback C# ?

Comment: `Action` is simply a generic delegate type - you could use whatever delegate type you want to send messages back. In the actual implementation, you would simply invoke the callback whenever you wanted to send a message.

Comment: I am trying to do it.
Just another question : My UI calls a .dll that calls secundary methods in secundary classes. The last "layer" of classes is the one who i want to send the message.

Can i write the callback there, and the other part in the UI or do i need to send the call back up every layer so that it reached the one  with the UI ?

Comment: It sounds like your UI has no visibility into the internals of the DLL, so you would need to pass the callback down all the layers of each thing as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating events in each of your crawler dlls, then in your main UI, subscribe to each of those events and report/display the results.

Comment: You mean, declare my own events and fire them after each step of the crawler ?

If my main thread (ui) is listening to the events, will it handle them without crashing the .dlls ?

Is there any reference you might give me ?

Comment: You might consider checking out [the MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on this.  I'm not 100% convinced this is the solution, but there's a good chance it is and you really should know how events work anyway.

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins yes, create your own events. UI should be able to handle those events just fine. See YYY link for events from MSDN. Also, if you still need to do stuff in the UI while the dll is crawling, fireoff the process via a BackgroundWorker, or on a separate thread...that way the UI remains responsive while the crawler is doing the work.